# Insert into table values only if one field value does not exist already

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to insert into table only when field_tag value which is not exist. I want to check prior to insert into the table..if the Receipt exist under the same field_tag value before. If not exist, then only i want to insert. I am using sql server 2008

```
INSERT INTO [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS]
           ([TicketNbr]
       ,[RevisionNbr]
           ,[Location_ID]
           ,[ContractNumber]
           ,[Storage_ID]
       ,[VarietyID]
           ,[GrossWeight]
           ,[TareWeight]
           ,[Carrier]
           ,[Receipt_date]
           ,[Last_update]
           ,[Inv_weight]
       ,[SAPBatch]
       ,[MoistureFactor]
       ,[Load_Harvested]
       ,[FIELDID]
       ,[GROWER_LOAD_NBR]
       ,[HARVEST_NBR]
       ,[TRACE_WORMS]
       ,[COR_CERT]
       ,[GFF_DEST]
---    ,[GFF_CONTRACT]
       ,[CAB_ID]
       ,[sOURCE]
       ,[CREATED_BY]
       ,[TOTALBONUSES]
       ,[PIDNUMBER] 
       ,[CARRIERVENDORID]
       ,[HAUL_ZONE]
       ,[FIELD_Tag]
       ,[Station]
       ,[COUNTY]
       ,[GradeDate]
       ,[Load_Received]
       ,[Load_Processed]

)
     VALUES
           (@CERT
      ,@RevisionNbr
           ,@Location_ID
           ,@ContractNUmber
           ,@Storage_ID
       ,@VarietyID
           ,@Gross_Weight
           ,@TareWeight
           ,@CarrierName
           ,@receipt_date
           ,Getdate()
           ,@Inv_weight
       ,@receiptbATCHnbr
       ,@DockageWeight
       ,@HARVEST_DT
       ,@FIELDID
       ,@GROWER_LOAD_NBR
       ,@HARVEST_NUMBER
       ,@TRACE_WORMS    
       ,@COR_CERT
       ,@GFF_DEST
---    ,@CONTRACT
       ,@CAB_ID
       ,'I'
       ,'Scale Interface'
       ,0
       ,@ContractPIDNumber
       ,@CARRIERID
       ,@HAUL_ZONE
       ,@FIELD_TAG
       ,@STATION
       ,@COUNTY
       ,@GRADE_DT
       ,@Arrival_dt
       ,@current_Date
)
```

I did like this :

```
insert into yourtable
(field1, field2, etc)
select value1, value2, etc
where not exists
( SELECT * FROM [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS] WHERE Field_Tag = @FIELD_TAG)
```

How to print the errors, I want to do error handling on this. If duplicate is there..it should print message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
insert into yourtable
(field1, field2, etc)
select value1, value2, etc
where not exists
(subquery to specify
condition under which you don't insert record)
```

**Edit Starts Here**

Another approach to notify user if record already exists

```
declare @Records as int;
set @Records = select count(*) from tbl_receipts
where field_tag = @Field_Tag;

if @Records > 0
begin
select 'record exists'
end

else
begin
insert query
select 'record added'
end
```

Comment: kind of similar, I want to know what to write in subquery and condition. The entire sp is up here http://pastebin.com/0yFAXM59

Comment: Incorrect syntax at SELECT in this statement  set @Records = SELECT count(*) from  [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS] WHERE field_tag = @Field_Tag;

Answer (score 0):

it is in working condition please test it. Entry will make in database if there is no entry of imei=69212 and description='dfhjsdfh'
`insert into events
  select 1,2,3 from ( 
    select 1 from events 
      where not exists ( 
        select 1 from events 
          where imei=69212 and description='dfhjsdfh' 
            group by imei) 
      group by imei) AS tt;`